# Как в WinForms подключить геолокацию данных клиента?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, логирование

Как подключить геолокацию данных клиента? Откуда и как брать данные страны? В запросах лога есть или имя хоста или ip адрес.

Comment: Уточнять смысл задания нужно у заказчика этого задания, еще лучше от заказчика получить тех.задание с описанием того, что он хочет получить. А спрашивать здесь случайных людей, что же имел в виду заказчик, что он хочет получить это знаете ли глупость.

Comment: может xml использовать.С xml полегче будет данные  выбирать

Comment: @Bulson так я же не само задание уточняю, допустим про геолокацию, с таким я никогда не сталкивался и в гугле инфы не нашел, вот и спрашиваю знающих

Comment: парсить на основе splita на мой взгляд нормальное решение, по-крайней мере я сам так часто делаю, а regexp-ом не всё решается.

Comment: 1. Задайте этот вопрос _отдельно_. 2. Из приложения WinForms сохраняете данные в БД. В приложении ASP читаете данные из БД. Эти приложения ничего не знают друг о друге.

Comment: Так не пойдёт! Верните прежний вопрос на место (упростив его). Потому что нынешний вариант совершенно не соответствует изначальному. И ответ, который уже дан, не подходит под вопрос.

Comment: А нынешний вариант вопроса задайте _отдельно_, создав _новую_ тему.

Comment: я бы с радостью, но почему то не могу задать новый вопрос, в данный момент. Могу дополнить этот вопрос , что бы он соответствовал ответу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соединить приложение WinForms и ASP.NET с одной базой ничего сложного нет.
Я думаю ты используешь Entity Framework.
Просто  в двух проектах делаешь одинаковые модели если есть и одинаковый класс для контекста и опять же одну и туже  строку подключения используешь.
Вот есть пример

Я тут приложение на WPF и ASP.NET MVC с одной базой взаимодействуют.
вот сервер

https://github.com/Ascolon/CinemaBackend

вот приложение для рабочего стола

https://github.com/Ascolon/CinameDesktop

В WPF приложении есть `Helper.cs`

и там метод

```
static public List<Movie> List()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://cinema.somee.com/api/values");
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    var root = new XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfMovie")
    {
        Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BackendPart.Models"
    };
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Movie>), root);
    var result = new List<Movie>();
    XmlDocument c = new XmlDocument();
    using (Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        result = (List<Movie>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
    return result;
}
```

идет запрос на сервер в ответ приходил XML документ.
Его на основе модели превращаем в `List` и там уже с коллекцией делаем что хотим

Вместо

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://cinema.somee.com/api/values");
```

адрес который будет при запуске сервера типа

```
`http://localhost:45344/api/values"`
```

Затем загружаем 100к записей.

```
BD.Record.Take(100000);
```

Не знаю, что в WinForms используется для отображения, но думаю `DataGridView`.
У него должны быть события на промотку скрола,
так вот когда скрол будет промотан до низу выполнить такой код

```
dataGridView.Items.AddRange(BD.Record.Skip(dataGridView.Items.Count).Take(10000);
```

То при промотки до конца он пропстит кол-во записнй которое уже есть в Гриде и добавть еще 100000.

Comment: Спасибо, за пример, но не совсем понял, где именно и как реализуется связь десктопа и бэка? Можете разъяснить, пожалуйста?

Comment: обновил ответ     аа

Comment: Вроде немного понял, спасибо , и еще такой вопрос, я в бд загружаю порядка двух миллионов записей ,записи(это обьекты) , потом обьекты заношу в общий список и оттуда уже загружаю в  datatable ,потом bulkcopy в бд. Во время добавления в datatable выскакивает исключение outofmemory . Что можете подсказать по этому поводу？Как сделать загрузку более рациональной и без исключений такого типа？

Comment: Ну можно например грузитьне сразу всего 2кк записей а например 100к.Потом когда скрол дойдет до низу подгрузитьеще 100 ка и так далее.

Comment: как это осуществляется в плане реализации？ тоесть как загружать по блокам？

Comment: обновил ответ про подзрузку данных

Comment: Спасибо, попробую